# Offset referencing another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a solution that would return the row below the cell I specified that is located in another Workbook. I've managed to get an address for cell, which I'll use as reference, by using formula

```
=ADDRESS(1;MATCH("*"&B1&".0.Raw";Raw_Actual.csv!$1:$1;0);1;TRUE;"[Raw_Actual.csv]Raw_Actual")
```

Which returns **[Raw_Actual.csv]Raw_Actual!$CH$1** where Raw_Actual.csv is name of file located in the same folder as my workfile.

Now using this address I'd like to get a value of a cell below that 
I wanted to use OFFSET Function so it goes 1 row below.

```
=OFFSET(=ADDRESS(1;MATCH("*"&B1&".0.Raw";Raw_Actual.csv!$1:$1;0);1;TRUE;"[Raw_Actual.csv]Raw_Actual");1;0)
```

Unfortunately, that returns a pop off with error. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your formula from:

```
=ADDRESS(1;MATCH("*"&B1&".0.Raw";Raw_Actual.csv!$1:$1;0);1;TRUE;"[Raw_Actual.csv]Raw_Actual")
```

To this:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1;MATCH("*"&B1&".0.Raw";Raw_Actual.csv!$1:$1;0);1;TRUE;"[Raw_Actual.csv]Raw_Actual"));1;0)
```

You need to use the Indirect formula to translate the result from address into an actual address, then you can use the Offset to get the row below.

Comment: Thank you. It works great! Before I was using HLOOKUP which was searching in huge array (1000x8760) and my file went from 900 KB to 3MB). Using your method it's only 1,3 MB which is life saver as the formula will be used for far bigger files than the original. I'm just wondering if Indirect is safe, as I've seen people mention it's volatile and uses a lot of resources for calculation.